# MVC redireccionar al incio de la aplicación

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buenas, tengo una aplicación MVC y cuando se ejecuta me lleva a IP:PUERTO pero necesito que me lleve a IP:PUERTO/Home/Index, en la clase RouteConfig tengo esto, pero no parece funcionar.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Index:

```
<form action="registrarCliente" method="post">

<input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" /> <input id="btnAdd"      type="submit" value="Añadir" />


</form>
<form action="eliminarCliente" method="post">

  <input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" /> <input id="btnDel"   type="submit" value="Eliminar" />


</form>
```

Comment: No es así como funcionan los valores por defecto de las rutas. La url que debería aparecerte debería ser, como comentas, `http://<ip>:<puerto>`, pero, al no especificar controlador ni acción, debería coger los indicados por defecto y tratar de ejecutar la acción `Index` del controlador `Home`. ¿Si depuras y pones un punto de ruptura en esta acción no pasa por ahí? ¿Te da algún error concreto?

Comment: Si que entra en la acción y no, no da nignun error, llega a mostrar los datos del Index, pero tengo unos ActionResult que al ejecutarlos dan errores, pero si me muevo a /Home/Index escribiendo la URL y ejecuto esos ActionResult si que funcionan.

Comment: Entonces el routing está funcionando bien. Entiendo que habrá algún problema en el código. Por lo que comentas tiene pinta que el problema está en la forma en la que creas las urls (en enlaces, formularios,...) para apuntar a esas otras acciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si utilizas ASP.NET MVC deberías utilizar los métodos que te proporciona este framework para gestionar las rutas.

Por ejemplo si quieres hacer una redirección a la acción `Index` de tu controlador `Home` no hagas un:

```
Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
```

Utiliza el método `RedirectToAction`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

En cualquier caso tu problema parece ser que los links creados en tu vista dependen de la url a través de la que se ha accedido a ella. Para evitarlo deberías utilizar los métodos que te proporcionan los helpers de ASP.NET MVC para generar las urls en función de tu configuración de rutas.

Por ejemplo, si quieres crear un link a una acción puedes utilizar el método `ActionLink`:

```
Html.ActionLink(texto_del_link, accion, controlador);
```

o para generar una url que apunte a una acción el método `Url.Action`:

```
Url.Action(accion, controlador)
```

Por ejemplo si tienes una acción `Ayuda` en tu controlador `HomeControler` y en tu vista `Index` incluyes un link:

```
<a href="Ayuda">Ayuda</a>
```

Si has accedido a través de la url `http://midominio_ip:puerto/Home/Index` te llevará correctamente a la url `http://midominio_ip:puerto/Home/Ayuda`, pero si la url de acceso es `http://midominio_ip:puerto` la url generada será `http://midominio_ip:puerto/Ayuda` con lo que ASP.NET MVC tratará de localizar la acción `Index` del controlador `Ayuda` que no es lo buscado.

Si ese mismo link lo creas utilizando los métodos de los helpers:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Ayuda", "Ayuda", "Home")
```

ASP.NET MVC se encargará de crear la url correcta que apunte a la acción indicada.

En tu caso podrías utilizar `Url.Action`:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("registrarCliente", "Home")" method="post">
    <input id="textCliente" name="textCliente"/>
    <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Añadir"/>
</form>
<form action="@Url.Action("eliminarCliente", "Home")" method="post">
    <input id="textCliente" name="textCliente"/>
    <input id="btnDel" type="submit" value="Eliminar"/>
</form>
```

O, mejor, `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("registrarCliente", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" />
    <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Añadir" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("eliminarCliente", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" />
    <input id="btnDel" type="submit" value="Eliminar" />
}
```

O incluso podrías crear también los `input` utilizando métodos del `HtmlHelper`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("registrarCliente", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Editor("textCliente")
    <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Añadir" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("eliminarCliente", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Editor("textCliente")
    <input id="btnDel" type="submit" value="Eliminar" />
}
```

Comment: Voy a editar mi pregunta y voy a añadir mis llamadas a los Actionresult para que veas como estan echos, gracias de antemano

Comment: He modificado la respuesta para mostrar cómo podrías hacerlo en tu caso concreto

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución, he añadido este código en el HomeController:

```
String URL = Request.Url.ToString();

if (!URL.Contains("/Home/Index"))
    Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
```

Comment: No me parece buena idea. La url que aparezca en el navegador no debería ser un problema para que funcione o no tu aplicación. De verdad que creo que el problema es que estás creando las urls a tus acciones directamente en lugar de utilizar los métodos de los helpers. Además con esa solución puedes tener otros problemas, por ejemplo te fallará si alojas tu aplicación en un directorio virtual.